# Slow MySQL order by datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have news table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modification_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mark_for_delete` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `published_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(511) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_1dmji5m90xaiy84vttgkvsub2` (`hash`),
  KEY `index_news_source` (`source`),
  KEY `index_news_creation_date` (`creation_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30887718 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And a join table to tag news belonging to some popular names:

```
CREATE TABLE `star_news` (
  `stars_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `news_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stars_id`,`news_id`),
  KEY `FK4eqjn8at6h4d9335q1plxkcnl` (`news_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1olc51y8amp8op1kbmx269bac` FOREIGN KEY (`stars_id`) REFERENCES `star` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK4eqjn8at6h4d9335q1plxkcnl` FOREIGN KEY (`news_id`) REFERENCES `news` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is my query to return the latest news

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.* 
FROM news n 
JOIN star_news sn 
  ON n.id = sn.news_id 
WHERE sn.stars_id IN (1234, 12345) 
ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC 
LIMIT 2;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                       | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sn    | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,FK4eqjn8at6h4d9335q1plxkcnl | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                  |196225|   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY | 8       | cosmos_dev.sn.news_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                      |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

This query takes 20 seconds on my machine. If I remove the order by clause it returns in sub milli second. How do I make the order by run faster?

I tried using force index on creation_date since its an indexed column, but it worsened the performance

Comment: Q: based on the normal types of queries you would run, in this case you are doing for 2 stars_id values (1234, 12345), how many TOTAL rows would be returned if you did not apply the limit 2 by creation_date descending.

Comment: ~196k (from the explain results)

Comment: I think it's impossible to find a simple "add-this-index" solution. Such index doesn't exists because you read records using one index and need to sort the result by other field from other table.

Comment: @akuzminsky I guess I could add a new column to star_news called news_date and create an index on (news_id, news_date).

Comment: You need to read and sort using same index. Then it will be fast. So, it has to be (stars_id, news_date) in the sn table.

Comment: But the `news_date` is an attribute of the `news` table, not the `star_news` table. Also it wouldn't help even if you added a `star_news.news_date` column and added it to the index as akusminsky suggests, because your condition on `stars_id` is a range condition (`IN( )`). The second column of that index wouldn't  optimize sorting, because the rows aren't read in the sorted order by `news_date`.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  How many rows for 1234 and for 12345?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 196k news articles relating to those 2 stars?  The explain extra tells you what is happening:

> Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

MySQL is creating a temporary file and sorting it to satisfy the order by because it could not use an index that would facilitate the join AND the ordering of articles by date.

Comment: Added the comp index. Same explain plan, force index on new index did not help either..

Comment: That wouldn't help. The query reads records by a field from one table (sn) and sorting by a field from another table (n).

Answer (score 0):

First, write the query as:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM news n 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM star_news sn 
              WHERE n.id = sn.news_id AND
                    sn.stars_id IN (1234, 12345) 
             )
ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC
LIMIT 2 ;
```

This eliminates the outer `SELECT DISTINCT`, which should help.

Then, create an index on `star_news(news_id, stars_id)`.  This might also take advantage of an index on `news(creation_date desc, id)`.

Comment: But this turns into a dependent sub query instead, that will be slow unless two articles about 1234 or 12345 are newly written.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand . . . Not necessarily.  Correlated subqueries can often be the fastest implementation for a query.  I haven't the faintest idea why so many people don't understand this.

Comment: If the Optimizer chooses to scan `n` by `creation_date`, it may be stuck checking 30887718 rows.